# Function for converting comma-separated input parameter into rows of int in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure where I am passing a CSV list of my values to be inserted into a table by the procedure.

My sp is

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `btwa`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_AddRole`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_AddRole`(IN _rolename VARCHAR(50) , IN _permissionList VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN 

        DECLARE _roleId INT;        
        INSERT INTO roles(RoleName, CreatedOn)
            VALUES    (_rolename,CURDATE());            
        SET _roleId = LAST_INSERT_ID();         
        /*INSERT INTO role_permissions(FkRoleId,FKPermissionId)
        VALUES (_roleId, ...);*/here I want to insert values of _permissionList 

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

How can I get rows of int from permissionList which I might pass like '1,2,3,4'

I have done development in SQL Server but not much in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I were able to done it via help of a forum post at http://www.slickdev.com/2008/09/15/mysql-query-real-values-from-delimiter-separated-string-ids/

My query looks like following

```
INSERT INTO role_permissions(FkRoleId,FKPermissionId)
        SELECT _roleId, permissionID FROM permissions WHERE FIND_IN_SET(permissionID, _permissionList);
```